# how can i get relation data by CActiverecord in yii?

Tags: php, yii, cactiverecord

I have 2 tables. tables have relation (HAS_MANY)
table1: user(id,name)
table2:address(id,userId,address)
user can has some address 
I define relation in moles: user.php and address.php

user.php

```
 'address' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'address', 'userId'),
```

address.php

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'user', 'userId'),
```

when i write

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('user')
```

i get only record of user table but i want to get records two table i want to get name,array(address) For each user , how can  do it?

UserController.php

```
public function actionIndex() {

         $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User');
        $this->render('index', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

index.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

_view.php

```
<b><?php echo $data->name)); ?>: <?php      $data->address->address;     ?>:</b>
```

Comment: where are you using `$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('user')` in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In indexaction function, change the dataprovider code as below.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User','criteria'=>array(
   'with'=>array(
       'address'
    ),
    'together'=>true,
));
```

You can get the data from `address` table using `$data->address->address_table_field_name` in your view file.

Here `address` is `relation` name defined in your user model file.

Comment: when i write $data->address->adress(name of field) i have error include(address.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: where did you used my answer?

Comment: in _view.php and i wite print_r($data) i have not any data about address

Comment: If you are using in `_view`, the you have to create your model object as `$model= User::model()->with('address')->findAll();` in view controller action. Then you will get address table fields.

Comment: i want to address relatet to users  ,  have not $dataProvider address filed?

Comment: What is your exact need and where to your output. Please mention Clearly file names and your code in question section.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$model= User::model()->with('address')->findAll();
```

**Note:-** `address` in **with('address')** is the relation Name.

**Eg:-**
To get **User records** try this

```
foreach($model as $record)
{
echo $record->id . $record->name;
}
```

To get **address records** try this

```
foreach($model as $record)
    {
    foreach($record->address as $myaddress)
{
echo $myaddress->id . $myaddress->userId . $myaddress->address;
}
    }
```

Comment: me by CActiveDataProvider i can not get relation data?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `CActiveDataProvider`, rather use the model directly.

Give it a try

```
foreach( User::model()->findAll() as $user ) {
   $address = $user->address;
   foreach( $address as $a ) {

   }
}
```